VITE various build processes inside the same "project"
Ok, so I have a self-made monorepo where i have several vite projects, for various purposes.
3 of those projects, are extemely coupled to each other and i would love to have them in the same "workspace" directory, sharing the same package.json.
This is the package.json i currently have for the main one of the three:
{
  "name": "editor",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "source ../../.env && bun x --bun vite build",
    "postbuild": "bun --env-file=../../.env ./postbuild.js"
  }
}

The three projects consist of:

"editor-app", this is te one in the package.json above

it's a react app which in postbuild i move the resulting js and css dist files, to where my production is.
I don't need the resulting index.html file, just the finished editor.js and editor.css resulting from my postbuild script


"editor-extension"

a chrome extension, that also compiles to a react-app


"editor-runtime"

a simple javascript module, that needs a final bundle, and needs no index.html or css
also has it's own postbuild



Ideally, i would want to have them all in the same "workspace", sharing a single package.json, that would look something like this:
{
  "name": "editor",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "bun build:app && bun build:extension && bun build:runtime", 
    "build:app": "source ../../.env && bun x --bun vite build src/app",
    "postbuild:app": "bun --env-file=../../.env ./postbuild-runtime.js",
    "build:runtime": "source ../../.env && bun x --bun vite build src/runtime",
    "postbuild:runtime": "bun --env-file=../../.env ./postbuild-runtime.js",
    "build:extension": "source ../../.env && bun x --bun vite build src/extension",
    "postbuild:extension": "bun --env-file=../../.env ./postbuild-extension.js",
  }
}

Obviously, each one of the 3 would need their own dist folder also.
Is this in any way possible?
How would i go about to achieve it?
Thank you
